# Twitter Bootstrap acting differently between running from file and from webserver

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to write a little site with the new Bootstrap 2 framework. I ran it the static html code by double clicking the file in my file browser and everything went fine. But when i uploaded it to a webhost it acts differently.

Locally, if the width of the browser is lower than 940px, then the menu is compactified as can be seen by this working example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html . But if I access the same file on my webhost, the links just stay the same.

I tried to minify my example but I still don't see how the change in behaviour is caused. So i put the minified example online and hope on you to help me.
You can see the file online here: http://users.skynet.be/ingdasite/miniCase/t.html . And you can download a zip-file of the files I extracted here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16797591/miniCase.zip .

update: the problem stays when I disable javascript, so it has to be a css-error

Comment: Your online page is blank, and the header just has a Home button - is that how it's supposed to look?

Comment: yes, i stripped everything else out, because the rest is not relevant to my question. That home button is supposed to dissapear if the page width is below 940px and it does not online, but it does if i access it via file:\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the responsive stylesheet ends with a .css file extension.

Once I renamed the file with a .css extension, it worked fine.

Also, you may want to move the responsive stylesheet underneath the style tag as follows:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
  }
</style>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will keep the navbar at the top instead of dropping it down when the browser width is less than 940px.

I have uploaded a modified version to Dropbox here: http://db.tt/CNB8GxAm

Reference: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1570

Comment: thank you very much, I really didn't knew the css-extension mattered